# SwiftUI - Button not switching image

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, boolean

so a really dumb issue occurred while trying to make a player play and pause button. So I've created a @State up top

```
    @State var isPlaying  : Bool = false
```

And then the button

```
        Button(action: {
                                    self.isPlaying.toggle()
                                    if self.isPlaying {
                                       player.pause()
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    player.play()
                                  }
                                    
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: self.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play.fill")
                                }
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.system(size:34))
```

It works, but on tap it plays the video without switching the sfSymbol from play to pause when video is running. It just uses the player.fill for both states when playing and when paused.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Code provided working fine. Xcode Version: 12.5.1 (12E507). Simulator Version: 12.5.1 (961.1). Note: As you didn't provide enough code I changed the "player.pause() / .start() to print()"

Answer (score 0):

Edit update:

works for me as well. This is the code I used for testing:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPlaying = false
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                isPlaying.toggle()
                if isPlaying {
                    player.pause()
                } else {
                    player.play()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause" : "play.fill")
            }
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
        }.font(.system(size:34))
    }
}
```